# Node child_process execute itself

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying to let a script execute itself again once it's finished, with different parameters this time.

```
child_process.exec(`node m.js ${newTimestamp} ${status.args[3]}`, (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
  console.log('test');
  if (err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
})
```

However it gets stuck and doesn't log anything at all. Not even `console.log('test')` line. But if I would change it to something else, for example:

```
child_process.exec(`pwd`, (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
  console.log('test');
  if (err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
})
```

it would run script and show output.

It seems that I am not understanding critical part about child processes, how do I deal with this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) :

```
callback <Function> called with the output when process terminates
```

This mean that execution of `node m.js` is still in process and callback will be called only when process will finish.
And that is why your callback get called with the `pwd` - it terminates after printing working directory to the stdout.

Take a look on [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) or [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) - they should fulfill your needs.

Looks like fork is what your are searching for:

> The child_process.fork() method is a special case of
>   child_process.spawn() used specifically to spawn new Node.js
>   processes. Like child_process.spawn(), a ChildProcess object is
>   returned. The returned ChildProcess will have an additional
>   communication channel built-in that allows messages to be passed back
>   and forth between the parent and child. See child.send() for details.

Comment: Qucik question about `.fork ~ on('close')` event. If I run `process.exit()` inside it, will it exit parent script and run new child from current child? And keep exiting and creating new childs as it goes?

Comment: The execution of close will be always be called in context of process on which it was triggered. So if you subscribe on process A you will get callback in process A too

Comment: But if a process A runs process B while B runs process C, and A calls `process.exit`, will B die too?

Comment: @Kunok I guess this thread will help you to understand. http://www.robsearles.com/2011/09/nodejs-experiments-with-processes/ 
Personally I haven't work with node.js that close.